# Dispatch a Paypal checkout to multiple account automatically

Tags: paypal, share

My website allows user to buy stuffs, and the payments will be splitted between a few people (generally 1/4 people).

So far, the processus I use is to receive the payment into one account, and then use the [Paypal Adaptive Payment API](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/adaptive_payments) to send this received payment to all the people, based on their percentage.

The problem with this solution is that the "reception paypal account" will have a lot of input/output money and will be the Achille's talon of my e-commerce (if this account is suspended, my commerce is down).

My question is quite simple: is there a way to do this automatically?

I found that if the buyer have a Paypal account, then I could directly use the Paypal API to dispatch it's payment (based on his paypal email) to the people, and that is perfect, but the problem is : what happens if the buyer doesn't have a paypal account and want to pay with, say, a credit card?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the solution is quite simple in fact but need a complete change :

I had to forget about Web checkout and use [Paypal API](http://www.paypal-labs.com/TechDocs/), do a [PAY request](https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-1413) with a Chained Payment (defining multiple receivers, with one (me) setted at `primary: true`). In that request, set the ipnNotificationUrl to be notified of the evolution of payments and that's it!

The response from paypal, if correct, will contain a paykey.

Then, you have to redirect the buyer to :

```
https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey={PAYKEY_HERE}
or
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey={PAYKEY_HERE}
```

Then, to be kept updated, all you have to do is send a request to Paypal containing the `paykey` to know the [paymentdetails](https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-1416) !

That's it !

Comment: When the customer hits check out, or whatever, to send them to paypal, is the checkout process the same as the express checkout for the user? I'm doing the exact same thing that you were doing in the first post..and am already using the PAY request for the second transaction..so I guess my ?'s are how do I send the client to paypal with all of the info that is in the form w/ Express checkout, and is the checkout process the same for the client as Express checkout? Your help is appreciated! This already helps a lot thanks!

Comment: From what I recall (it's been a long time ;)), Express Checkout is different from the checkout process. But you can manage your basket internally, and then when the client hit pay, you send a Pay request to paypal by adding items one by one, Paypall will tell you the total with a unique token, and you direct your client to the paypal payment url including the token. (Did I understood correctly?)

Comment: Interesting, okay yea I think I understand. When I looked into it further I was having difficulty with the order that Paypal does things in. It seems that you make the pay request and identify the receiver/s before you identify the payer, and then they give you the "pay_key" and you can plug that into the payment url. Does that sound right to you? I guess it makes sense now, but it's not the most intuitive way of doing it, and I think u can also identify a payer from the start. I'm assuming the unique token you're talking about is the pay_key? Thanks for your help, I know this was an old post!

Comment: Yes it's the way paypal except. You add the pay_key in the url to identify yourself (+ the payment) to paypal when you redirect the user. Moreover, all future notifications (ipn) will contains this pay_key.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my question on that, looking into the [Paypal Adaptive Payment API](http://www.paypal-labs.com/TechDocs/), we can see a dedicated section "Guest Payments".

It seems it's possible, but it requires all the people that will receive the money to have a **Business** Account or **Premium** account!

Answer (score 0):

Well I'll add a second answer because it's more complete and slightly different from the first one.

The best way to do it quite simply is to use the [Express Checkout](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECGettingStarted) API (SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails, DoExpressCheckoutPayment).

By using it instead of the basic "checkout" bouton with an IPN behind, it is possible to define more than one recipient that will receive the money : [the parallel payment](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECParallelPaymens).

It's that easy!

(Now I have to rewrite all my code to implement it, yayh!)